# Crystal Reports Assembly Deployment on Appharbor

Tags: crystal-reports, appharbor

When deploying a new version of my application to Appharbor that uses the Crystal Reports assembly: **CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine** I receive the following error message in the appharbor deployment log:

```
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
Primary reference "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. 
Could not locate the assembly "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL". 
Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I've set "Copy Local" to True in the assembly reference in VS & the DLL exists in the project \BIN directory.

Do I need create a local (non GAC) copy of the DLL and then reference it in the project? If so how does one do this without the GAC version still being referenced?

Or am I doing something wrong with the deploy?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 4):

You should add the dll to local `/lib` folder that you push along with your code. The simplest way to ensure that you're referencing the correct dll is to remove the original from the GAC and then make sure that your code works.

Comment: Following the first approach (coping dll to a local /lib folder) enabled the deployment to build. However during runtime the Crystal Engine throws up an error. The following [link](https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567)  outlines that the Crystal run time needs to be installed via an MSI and that coping dll will not work. Would Appharbor support this approach for installing Crystal?

Comment: Hm, it seems that bin-deploying the dll's should work: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/05/22/2597.aspx - AppHarbor will not be installing the Crystal Reports runtime on application servers.